# Strange IE9 only error Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, jquery-isotope

We are hitting a very strange and confusing error that's preventing the rendering of some Javascript. I've googled and can't seem to find a solution, and I know this is pretty vague, but figured I would ask.

The issue is occurring in IE9 only. We are thinking it is stopping our other scripts from running, and is probably unrelated to Backbone.

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'apply': object is null or undefined 
application.js, line 86 character 2366
```

Greatly appreciate anyone's help on this one, it's really stumping us.

Comment: Just for anyone trying to fix this, adding this to my header worked: **<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to the head section of the document before the JS was rendered fixed the issue!

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```